# Import a function from a module in another folder in parent directory

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

I have been trying unsuccessfully to solve this for hours now.
This is my folder structure.

```
/parent_folder
      main.py
      module1/
        script1.py
      module2/
        script2.py
```

`script2.py` has only this inside:

```
def subtract_numbers(x, y):
    return x - y
```

I want script1.py to be able to call this function.
I have:

```
from ..module2.script2 import subtract_numbers

result_subtraction = subtract_numbers(5, 5)
print(result_subtraction)
```

I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

I have tried many different permutations in the import line in `scrip1.py` but i get the same error. I also have to note that i have `__init__.py` files in the two folders.

How exactly can i call the function in `script2.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

I exported the directory of the parent directory (`/parent_folder`) to the `PYTHONPATH`.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/username/Desktop/parent_folder
```

Then, inside file `module1/script1.py`, i had this line changed:

```
from module2.script2 import subtract_numbers
```

Now i can call the script `script1.py` that calls the function declared in `module2/script2.py` with `python script1.py` and it will work.

I also have to note that i have `__init__.py` files everywhere (in the parent directory and both subfolders), but i am now sure if this is vital.

Answer (score 1):

Relative imports cannot go back to a higher level than the one from which the `python` call was originated. So, your problem here is that you are invoking `script1.py` directly from the `module1` directory. I guess something like this:

```sh
user:/path/to/parent/module1$ python script1.py
```

So you will need to make your call to `script1.py` from a level where you can actually see `script2.py`.

First, change your relative import to absolute import in `script1.py`:

```py
from module2.script2 import subtract_numbers
```

Then, *move back to the parent directory* of `module1` and run the module as a script from there (note the location in the prompt):

```sh
user:/path/to/parent$ python -m module1.script1
```

Comment: Thanks. You said "Relative imports cannot go back to a higher level than the one from which the python call was originated." Can't this be performed with something like absolute imports to have a permanent solution?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I don't see another solution in this case. If you want to avoid using the `python -m` and call a script directly, what you can do is create another script, let's say script0.py at the level of the parent directory, and `import module1.script1` into it. Then you can run `python script0.py` from there, but that doesn't help you much more I think.